# I have problem with rotation; rotatetoToTarget;

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to 2dgameobject turns toward to target 2dgameobject
I have a Method - rotate to target.
Code:

```c#
Quaternion rawRoation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation,
            Quaternion.LookRotation(Player.GetComponent<Transform>().position - transform.position),
            10*Time.deltaTime);
transform.rotation = new Quaternion (0, 0, rawRoation.z, rawRoation.w);
```

Problem - WHen target's position.x < this.object.transform.position.x(1) - rotation breaks..
else(2) - all right.

1 -
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRvyn.png)

2 - [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yPOv.png)

Comment: This method locates in "Update(){}"

Comment: Please edit your question with descriptions of the images. Notice the place holder text that says `enter image description here`. that helps other users understand your question better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line of code: `transform.rotation = new Quaternion (0, 0, rawRoation.z, rawRoation.w);`

I don't know what you want to achieve, but if you want to nullify the x and y rotation use:

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, 0.0f, rawRoation.eulerAngles.z);
```

Example of what your code does:

```
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    Quaternion q1 = new Quaternion(0.3f, 0.7f, 0.4f, 0.5f);
    Quaternion q2 = new Quaternion(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.5f);

    Debug.Log(q1.eulerAngles);
    Debug.Log(q2.eulerAngles);
}
```

And here the output:

```
q1: (344.8, 100.3, 59.1)
q2: (0.0, 0.0, 77.3)
```

**Please have a look at the math of quaternions**

**Edit - 2D LookAt:**

Your code does not work like you want because you are in 2D. If you want to look at a target with an x-position less than your object's in 3D you have to do a rotation around the y-axis by 180deg which in 2D is not a valid rotation. You cannot. You do this y-rotation to prevent that the object is upside down. but in 2D you cannot do such a rotation.

**You have to choices:**

1. If your camera looks from the side and your object can be upside down use your modified code and also set the x-scale to -1 if the targets x-position is less.
2. If your camera looks from top down use the following
   code:

**Code for upside down view:**

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update() {
    Vector3 targetDir = target.position - transform.position;
    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(targetDir.y, targetDir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    Quaternion q = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, q, Time.deltaTime * 10);
}
```

Comment: Thanks,it's not my code and im null in quaternions. I want to object turns toward to target, and if targets.x > objects.x, then my code works, but else - nope. You showed me  my mistake, but may you help me in my task? - turn 2dgameobject toward to target2dgameobject.
p.s. Im sorry if im too impudent, im russian  :D

Comment: **Edit - 2D LookAt**